# Remove all what in the saved listview and increment by one with every new update

Tags: android, listview, increment

I am trying to write a set of names and save them in a list view, however I need that every time I can update the list all what was in it is cleared and I add all the new updates, also the list dynamically has an increment that increments by one with every update.

How can I do that please as I am stuck with my saved list and can not remove any old in formations, Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an Adapter, it will contain the info displayed in the ListView.
If you want to remove all the info displayed in the ListView, just remove the info contained in the Adapter, set a new one and notifyDataChanged().

Comment: thanks for that, and can you inform me please how to save using file output stream from edittext in only ONE file withe the same name, as I made it like that

FILENAME = editext.getText().toString();
  
     edittext.setText("");
      
  try {
   FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   fos.write(JOUR.getBytes()); 
   fos.close();

And how can I add couters

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite to store the list data and populate the list using a CursorAdapter. When you add items to your table it will show up in your listview. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for more information on using the sqlite database in android.